# filetype filter does not work in php file upload

Tags: php, ajax, file, upload

I want to let my users to upload image just in PNG and JPG anf JPEG filetypes .
So I use this code in my html File :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src='jquery.min.js' ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        function upload_start(){
              document.getElementById('upload-process').style.visibility = 'visible';
              return true;
        }

        function upload_end(check_upload){
          var server_response = '';
          if (check_upload == 1){
             server_response = '<span class="ok">File Uploaded<\/span>';
          }
          else {
             server_response = '<span class="error">file Upload error<\/span>';
          }
          document.getElementById('upload-process').style.visibility = 'hidden';
          document.getElementById('upload-form').innerHTML = server_response;
          return true;   
    }
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>

            <form action="php-ajax-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload-target" onsubmit="upload_start();">
            <label for="user-file"></label>
            <input type="file" id="user-file" name="user-file" />
            <input type="hidden" name="customer_id"  value="6000" />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
            </form>
```

And the `php-ajax-upload.php` content is :

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
$customer_id = $_POST['customer_id'] ;

if ( ($_FILES["user-file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" )|| ($_FILES["user-file"]["type"] == "image/jpg" )|| ($_FILES["user-file"]["type"] == "image/png" ) ) 
{
    if ($_FILES["user-file"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "<div class=\"server\">Error: " . $_FILES["user-file"]["error"] . "</div><br />";
        $check_result = 0;
        }
    else{
        if (file_exists("user-upload/" . $_FILES["user-file"]["name"])){
            echo "<div class=\"server\">This file exists <br /><br />".$_FILES["user-file"]["name"]. "</div><br />";
            $check_result = 0;      
            }
        else{
                if(isset($_POST['customer_id']) && !empty($_POST['customer_id'])  )
                {
                    $customer_id = trim($_POST['customer_id']);

                    $filename  = basename($_FILES['user-file']['name']);
                    $format = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $saved_file_name = $customer_id.'.'.$format ;
                    if(is_writable(dirname(__FILE__) . './admin-upload/'. $saved_file_name))
                    {
                      unlink(dirname(__FILE__) . './admin-upload/'. $saved_file_name ); 
                    }

                    if(is_writable(dirname(__FILE__) . './admin-upload/'.$customer_id.'.jpeg'))
                    {
                      unlink(dirname(__FILE__) . './admin-upload/'.$customer_id.'.jpeg' ); 
                    }

                    if(is_writable(dirname(__FILE__) . './admin-upload/'.$customer_id.'.jpg'))
                    {
                      unlink(dirname(__FILE__) . './admin-upload/'.$customer_id.'.jpg' ); 
                    }

                    if(is_writable(dirname(__FILE__) . './admin-upload/'.$customer_id.'.png'))
                    {
                      unlink(dirname(__FILE__) . './admin-upload/'.$customer_id.'.png' ); 
                    }
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["user-file"]["tmp_name"],"admin-upload/".$customer_id.'.'.$format ) ;
                    $check_result = 1;

                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'Id not found !';
                    $check_result = 0;  
                }
            }
    }
}

else{
    if($_FILES["user-file"]["size"] > 1000000){
        echo "<div class='server red bold'>File is Large</div>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<div class='server red bold'> File Type is not Valid !</div>";
    }
    $check_result = 0;
}

?>


<script type="text/javascript">
window.top.window.upload_end(<?php echo $check_result; ?>);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

now when I want to check my code , when I select an Imange ir works good ,also when I select other file types like : pdf , doc , srt , ....  the code works good and will say : 
**File Type is not Valid !**
but only when I select an `mp3` file , `php-ajax-upload.php` file errors :

> Notice: Undefined index: customer_id in D:\Software\wamp\www\garanti\php-ajax-upload.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: user-file in
>   D:\Software\wamp\www\garanti\php-ajax-upload.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: user-file in
>   D:\Software\wamp\www\garanti\php-ajax-upload.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: user-file in
>   D:\Software\wamp\www\garanti\php-ajax-upload.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: user-file in
>   D:\Software\wamp\www\garanti\php-ajax-upload.php on line 64

And finally at the end of page says :

**File Type is not Valid !**

I dont Know why this error will happen only for mp3 files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it might be related to one of your php.ini settings.

I am assuming that the `mp3` file is larger than any other files you have tried successfully to upload. If the size of the file is greater than the `php.ini` setting `post_max_size` then PHP will loose data from the post and I think that is what has happened here. The mp3 file may have uploaded, but the other variables that also come in the POST are being lost.

Check `post_max_size` its default value is 3Meg and you may have to increase it. Remember it will need to be > that `upload_max_filesize` to ensure you dont loose these other POST variiables.